# Is Schwartz space closed under multiplication and convolution?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, schwartz-space

I think the both answer is "yes".

How can I prove that Schwartz space is closed under multiplication ?

Because if I know that, it is easy to see that being closed under convolution is satisfied.

Help me please.

Thanks

Comment: Product rule. $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$, so if $f,g,f'$ and $g'$ all die faster than $(1+|x|)^{-\alpha}$ for every $\alpha$ then so does $(fg)'$. Of course writing this out for higher derivatives and several variables will be a pain. Probably there's a product rule/Leibniz formula for $D^\alpha(fg)$ in the book...

Comment: Since it is closed under Fourier transform and the Fourier transform maps convolutions to products...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f, g \in \mathscr S$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are multi-indices,
what is $x^\alpha D^\beta(f g)$?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a answer to a similar question, and this answer is due to Davide, not me. I remark that, with some obvious modification, his proof can be applied to this question.

This is the link:
[Schwartz Space is closed under differentiation and multiplication by polynomials.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026991/schwartz-space-is-closed-under-differentiation-and-multiplication-by-polynomials)